# Performance issues with flash file - places to start looking for the underlying issue?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, animation, flash, lag

I am currently working on a small flash application as a supplementary gimmick to a job application ( as 2D artist ). It has been the first time working with flash for both me and my friend who took over coding, already noting that both flash as an engine and AS3 are a bit particular at times.

The flash file lags but we cannot figure out the issues causing the lag.
For the graphics, mostly photoshop processed pngs and a few illustrator files for the hitboxes are used.

The code itself:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


{ /* MAIN */

stop();
stage.focus = stage;

var initDone: Boolean
if (!initDone) {
    // stop all movie clips that have more than 1 frame
    stopMovieClips(chair, credits, cup, cvinv, doll, hat, kaktus, karpfen, karpfenhit, laptop, log, luke1, luke3, mini, paper, pickles, portfolio, portfolioinv, poster, pylon, rkcard, smoke, sylvanas, talk_long, talk_short, textbox, trash, triforce, trophy, worbla);

    // mask all hitboxes transparent
    setMovieClipsTransparent(chairhit, cuphit, cvinvhit, dollhit, hathit, kaktushit, karpfenhit, laptophit, lukehit, minihit, portfolioinvhit, paperhit, pickleshit, posterhit, pylonhit, rkcardhit, sylvanashit, trashhit, triforcehit, trophyhit, worblahit);

    // set hitboxes inactive
    setMovieClipsInactive(cvinvhit, portfolio, pickleshit, portfolioinvhit, rkcardhit, triforcehit);

    // mask other movie clips transparent
    setMovieClipsTransparent(cvinv, log, luke3, pickles, portfolio, portfolioinv, rkcard, talk_long, talk_short, triforce);

    //start background animations
    //talk_standard.gotoAndPlay(1);

    //set initialization as done
    trace("Initialization completed.");
    initDone = true;
}


}

{ /* EVENT LISTENER */

{ /* INFLATE OBJECTS ON MOUSEOVER */
    chairhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(chair, textbox, "chair", talk_long, talk_standard));
    cuphit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(cup, textbox, "cup", talk_long, talk_standard));
    cvinvhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(cvinv, textbox, "cvinv", talk_long, talk_standard));
    dollhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(doll, textbox, "doll", talk_long, talk_standard));
    hathit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(hat, textbox, "hat", talk_short, talk_standard));
    kaktushit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(kaktus, textbox, "kaktus", talk_short, talk_standard));
    karpfenhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(karpfen, textbox, "karpfen", talk_short, talk_standard));
    laptophit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(laptop, textbox, "laptop", talk_long, talk_standard));
    //lukehit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, inflate(luke, textbox, "luke", null, null));
    minihit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(mini, textbox, "mini", talk_short, talk_standard));
    paperhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(paper, textbox, "paper", talk_long, talk_standard));
    portfolioinvhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(portfolioinv, textbox, "portfolioinv", talk_long, talk_standard));
    pickleshit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(pickles, textbox, "pickles", talk_long, talk_standard));
    posterhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(poster, textbox, "poster", talk_long, talk_standard));
    pylonhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(pylon, textbox, "pylon", talk_short, talk_standard));
    rkcardhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(rkcard, textbox, "rkcard", talk_long, talk_standard));
    sylvanashit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(sylvanas, textbox, "sylvanas", talk_long, talk_standard));
    trashhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(trash, textbox, "trash", talk_short, talk_standard));
    triforcehit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(triforce, textbox, "triforce", talk_short, talk_standard));
    trophyhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(trophy, textbox, "trophy", talk_short, talk_standard));
    worblahit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inflate(worbla, textbox, "worbla", talk_long, talk_standard));
}

{ /* DEFLATE OBJECTS ON MOUSEOUT */
    chairhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(chair, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    cuphit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(cup, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    cvinvhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(cvinv, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    dollhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(doll, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    hathit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(hat, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    kaktushit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(kaktus, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    karpfenhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(karpfen, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    laptophit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(laptop, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    //lukehit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(luke, textbox, null, null));
    minihit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(mini, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    paperhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(paper, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    pickleshit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(pickles, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    portfolioinvhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(portfolioinv, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    posterhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(poster, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    pylonhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(pylon, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    rkcardhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(rkcard, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    sylvanashit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(sylvanas, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
    trashhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(trash, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    triforcehit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(triforce, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    trophyhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(trophy, textbox, talk_short, talk_standard));
    worblahit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, deflate(worbla, textbox, talk_long, talk_standard));
}

{ /* ADD TO INVENTORY ON MOUSE CLICK */
    paperhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addToInventory(portfolioinv, portfolioinvhit));
    laptophit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addToInventory(triforce, triforcehit));
    hathit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addToInventory(pickles, pickleshit));
    chairhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addToInventory(rkcard, rkcardhit));
    posterhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addToInventory(cvinv, cvinvhit));
}

{ /* TIMED LISTENERS */
    var randomBlockLuke: Boolean;
    var randomTimerLuke: Timer = new Timer(60 * 1000) // start INITIAL animation after set time (in milliseconds)
    randomTimerLuke.start();
    randomTimerLuke.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, randomTimedAnimation(luke1, randomTimerLuke, 20000, 45000, randomBlockLuke));
}


{ /* SPECIAL LISTENERS */
    var karpfenExchanged: Boolean = false;
    var kawarimiSound: kagebunshin = new kagebunshin();
    //var karpfenRevertTimer: Timer = new Timer(0);

    karpfenhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kawarimi(karpfen, smoke, log, karpfenhit, 13, karpfenExchanged, /*karpfenRevertTimer,*/ kawarimiSound));
    //karpfenRevertTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, kawarimi(karpfen, karpfenhit, smoke, log, karpfenhit, 13, karpfenExchanged, karpfenRevertTimer, kawarimiSound));

    var clickcounterLuke: uint = 0;
    lukehit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, multiObjectAnimation(luke1, randomBlockLuke, clickcounterLuke, true, luke3));

    trashhit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function () {
        credits.gotoAndStop("credits")
    });
    credits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function () {
        credits.gotoAndStop("normal")
    });
    //titlescreen.titlebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closepopup(titlescreen));
}
}




{ /* FUNKTIONEN */

function inflate(mc1: MovieClip, mc2: MovieClip, textpos: String, mcStartAnim: MovieClip = null, mcStopAnim: MovieClip = null): Function {
    return function (e: MouseEvent): void {
        mc1.gotoAndStop("bump");
        mc2.gotoAndStop(textpos);

        if (mcStartAnim != null) {
            mcStartAnim.alpha = 1;
            if (mcStopAnim != null) {
                mcStopAnim.alpha = 0;
                mcStopAnim.gotoAndPlay(0);
            };

            mcStartAnim.addFrameScript(mcStartAnim.totalFrames - 1, lastFrameReached);
            mcStartAnim.gotoAndPlay(1);

            function lastFrameReached(): void {
                mcStartAnim.gotoAndStop(1);
                if (mcStopAnim != null) {
                    mcStartAnim.alpha = 0;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};

function deflate(mc1: MovieClip, mc2: MovieClip, mcStopAnim: MovieClip = null, mcStartAnim: MovieClip = null): Function {
    return function (e: MouseEvent): void {
        mc1.gotoAndStop("normal");
        mc2.gotoAndStop(1);

        if (mcStopAnim != null) {
            mcStopAnim.gotoAndStop(1);
            if (mcStartAnim != null) {
                mcStartAnim.gotoAndPlay(1);
                mcStartAnim.alpha = 1;
                mcStopAnim.alpha = 0;
            };
        };
    };
};

function kawarimi(mcBefore: MovieClip, mcAnim: MovieClip, mcAfter: MovieClip, mcHit: MovieClip, exchangeFrame: int = -1, statusExchanged: Boolean = false, /*timerRevert: Timer = null,*/ mcAnimSound: * = null): Function {
    var blocked: Boolean = false;
    var instance: MovieClip = this;
    return function (e: MouseEvent): void {
        if (!blocked) {
            blocked = true;
            var mcBeforeTmp: MovieClip;
            var mcAfterTmp: MovieClip;
            var mcHitFrame: uint;

            if (statusExchanged) {
                mcBeforeTmp = mcAfter;
                mcAfterTmp = mcBefore;
                mcHitFrame = 2;

            } else {
                mcBeforeTmp = mcBefore;
                mcAfterTmp = mcAfter;
                mcHitFrame = 1;
            }
            /*
            if (timerRevert != null) {
                timerRevert.stop();
            };
*/

            //setMovieClipsInactive(mcBeforeHitTmp);

            //mc2.x = mc1.x - mc1.width/2 - mc2.width/2;
            //mc2.y = mc1.y + mc1.height/2 + mc1.height/2;
            mcAnim.addFrameScript(mcAnim.totalFrames - 1, lastFrameReached);


            if (exchangeFrame < 0) {
                exchangeFrame = 1;
            } else if (exchangeFrame >= mcAnim.totalFrames) {
                exchangeFrame = mcAnim.totalFrames;
            };
            mcAnim.addFrameScript(exchangeFrame - 1, exchangeAssets);


            mcAnim.gotoAndPlay(2);
            if (mcAnimSound != null) {
                mcAnimSound.play();
            };


            function lastFrameReached(): void {
                mcAnim.gotoAndStop(1);
                /*
                if (!statusExchanged && timerRevert != null) {
                    timerRevert.delay = 10000;
                    timerRevert.repeatCount = 1;
                    timerRevert.start();
                    trace("Timer started");
                }
*/
                statusExchanged = !statusExchanged;
                blocked = false;
            };

            function exchangeAssets(): void {
                mcBeforeTmp.alpha = 0;
                mcAfterTmp.alpha = 1;
                mcHit.gotoAndStop(mcHitFrame);
            };
        };
    };
};


function setMovieClipsTransparent(...listMC): void {
    for each(var mc: MovieClip in listMC) {
        mc.alpha = 0;
    };
};

function stopMovieClips(...listMC): void {
    for each(var mc: MovieClip in listMC) {
        mc.stop();
    };
};

function setMovieClipsInactive(...listMC): void {
    for each(var mc: MovieClip in listMC) {
        mc.mouseEnabled = false;
        mc.mouseChildren = false;
    };
};

function setMovieClipsActive(...listMC): void {
    for each(var mc: MovieClip in listMC) {
        mc.mouseEnabled = true;
        mc.mouseChildren = true;
    };
};

function addToInventory(mcObj: MovieClip, mcHit: MovieClip): Function   {
    return function (e: MouseEvent): void {
        mcObj.alpha = 1;
        setMovieClipsActive(mcHit);
    }
}


function randomTime(minTime: uint, maxTime: uint): uint {
    var range: uint = maxTime - minTime;
    var Time: Number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minTime;
    return (Time);
};

function randomTimedAnimation(mc1: MovieClip, timer: Timer, minTime: uint, maxTime: uint, blockObject: Boolean = true): Function {
    return function (e: TimerEvent): void {
        if (!blockObject) {
            blockObject = true;
            mc1.addFrameScript(mc1.totalFrames - 1, lastFrameReached);
            mc1.gotoAndPlay(1);

function lastFrameReached(): void {
                mc1.gotoAndStop(1);

                var interval: uint = randomTime(minTime, maxTime);
                timer.delay = interval;
                trace("Timer for " + mc1.name + " started with " + interval + " milliseconds.");
                blockObject = false;
            };
        };
    };
}

function multiObjectAnimation(mc1: MovieClip, blockObject: Boolean = true, clickcounter: uint = 0, onlyif: Boolean = true, ...listMC): Function {
    var blocked: Boolean = false;

    return function (e: MouseEvent): void {
        if (!blocked) {
            blocked = true;
            blockObject = true;

            if (clickcounter >= listMC.length - 1) { // if all elements have been iterated once...
                clickcounter = 0; // ...then reset clickcounter and start from anew.
                trace("Resetted click counter for " + mc1.name + ".");
            };


            mc1.gotoAndStop(1);
            listMC[clickcounter].gotoAndStop(1);
            mc1.alpha = 0;
            listMC[clickcounter].alpha = 1;

            listMC[clickcounter].addFrameScript(listMC[clickcounter].totalFrames - 1, lastFrameReached);
            listMC[clickcounter].gotoAndPlay(1);

            function lastFrameReached(): void {
                listMC[clickcounter].gotoAndStop(1);
                mc1.gotoAndStop(1);
                mc1.alpha = 1;
                listMC[clickcounter].alpha = 0;
                clickcounter += 1;
                trace("Set click counter for " + mc1.name + " to: " + clickcounter + ".");
                blocked = false;
                blockObject = false;
            };
        };
    };
};



function gotoFrame(mc1: MovieClip, frameLabel: String, alpha: int = -1): Function {
    return function (e: MouseEvent): void {
        if (alpha >= 0) { // only change alpha is a value is specified in function call
            mc1.alpha = alpha;
        };
        switch (frameLabel) {
            case "previous":
                if (mc1.currentFrame == 1) {
                    mc1.gotoAndStop(mc1.totalFrames);
                } else {
                    mc1.gotoAndStop(mc1.currentFrame - 1);
                };
                break;
            case "next":
                if (mc1.currentFrame == mc1.totalFrames) {
                    mc1.gotoAndStop(1);
                } else {
                    mc1.gotoAndStop(mc1.currentFrame + 1);
                };
                break;
            case "first":
                mc1.gotoAndStop(1);
                break;
            case "last":
                mc1.gotoAndStop(mc1.totalFrames);
                break;
            default:
                mc1.gotoAndStop(frameLabel);
                break;
        };

    };
};


};
```

The game on my page: https://www.schwarzsarah.com/flash
Flashfile on GoogleDrive because game on page causes issues: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SnsX-LULbFCGdqTJWkzqkhe7Ie5qCZOR

According to Adobe Scout, the goToAndPlay commands are using up the most power, but even after disabling them nothing changed.

Is there anything one should keep in mind for the graphics and code?

A big thank you in advance for any possible help.

Comment: I do not have experience with flash so cannot answer, sorry, but if I may: you should not start learning flash in 2019 because this technology is obsolete and soon web browsers will drop support (if not already). Try to use HTML5 and javascript instead.

Comment: Realized that, but I did not even intend to make something overly complex at the beginning so we just went with the flash thing I started.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers Nobody cares about the browser and their plugins. Asker is a **2D artist** and Adobe Flash is a perfectly fine choice for (interactive) graphics, it will even output as native apps for mobiles (Android/iOS) or desktops. Saying _"Try to use HTML5 and javascript instead"_ is the wrong advice to give an artist (is not a web page coder)...

Comment: What is "lag" for you? I opened your app and it seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Reaction times to the triggers and the animations (try clicking the fish, we had the smoke explosion play quite smoother and quicker earlier in the coding process, set framerate is 20 fps which is not what the output is up to). As for the code, done by someone who knows coding but just still has some issues with the special way flash works sometimes.

Comment: Hi Sarah welcome to the site. Use the **@** symbol to notify someone of your response to them. Your last comment I think is for @Organis

Comment: @SarahSchwarz Oh, I get it now. The "Flash" item there just doesn't run for me at all.

Comment: @SarahSchwarz which is why i threw it onto the drive because since it ran for me, I did not think it would cease to function at all with other systems. Well, now I know and that ain't good. I'm using Firefox and the standart flash app plugin provided by the page builder I use (wix) and test the thing offline with SWF file player...with no difference to animation speed.

Comment: @SarahSchwarz Oh, I see lags now. Are you sure these all are PNGs? They look pretty vector-y to me.

Comment: @VC.One ok, sorry. I'll now better next time.

Comment: @Organis absolutely. The only vector files are the item doubles I ran through autotracing in Illustrator to get the correct hitboxes since that was the way for us to go in terms of hitbox collision detection (as pngs have square hitboxes that would trigger even when clicking the "empty" transparent spaces). Because my wacom tablet was not working when I started this, the outlines were drawn with inking pen and paper, scanned and got a two tone shading with photoshop and saved as pngs.

Comment: @SarahSchwarz I looked through your code, and that's what I have to say. I don't know if the code is to blame for these lags, but the style is **extremely** weird. The use of undocumented **addFrameScript**, then functions inside functions inside functions, programming **SimpleButton** functionality instead of outright use of **SimpleButton**s... who knows.

Comment: @Organis we know that it is not solved in the most elegant way at times but are also a bit clueless on what needs to be written better to increase performance

Comment: @SarahSchwarz I'd really start with converting these weird parts of the script into button objects (in the project's Library): they have 4 frames: up state, over state, down state and the **hit area** frame which is the area that is the mouse interactive area. If the **hit area** is not empty and filled properly, then the button wont react with its transparent corners.

Answer (score 0):

Many times animations having tween such as shape tween, motion tween can be a factor causing lag. Also gradient can cause lag. In your game, on clicking fish I see a cloud like animation. Try removing that and few other animations and check.